# Opencv get R and t from Essential Matrix

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I'm new to opencv and computer vision. I want to find the R and t matrix between two camera pose. So I generally follows the wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_matrix#Determining_R_and_t_from_E

I find a group of the related pixel location of the same point in the two images. I get the essential matrix. Then I run the SVD. And print the 2 possible R and 2 possible t.

**[What runs as expected]**

If I only change the rotation alone (one of roll, pitch, yaw) or translation alone (one of x, y, z), it works perfect. For example, if I increase pitch to 15 degree, then I would get R and find the delta pitch is +14.9 degree. If I only increase x for 10 cm, then the t matrix is like [0.96, -0.2, -0.2].

**[What goes wrong]**

However, if I change both rotation and translation, the R and t is non-sense. For example, if I increase x for 10 cm and increase pitch to 15 degree, then the delta degree is like [-23, 8,0.5], and the t matrix is like [0.7, 0.5, 0.5].

**[Question]**

I'm wondering why I could not get a good result if I change the rotation and translation at the same time. And it is also confusing why the unrelated rotation or translation (roll, yaw, y, z) also changes so much.

Would anyone be willing to figure me out? Thanks.

---

**[Solved and the reason]**

OpenCV use a right-hand coordinate system. This is to say that the z-axis is projected from xy plane to the viewer direction. And our system is using a left-hand coordinate system. So as long as the changes are related to the z-axis, the result is non-sense.

Comment: You were using only one camera but in different poses, right?
Have you ever tried to use two cameras to take a stereo image pair? If so, how did you calculate the essential matrix? (I assumed you also use opencv's findEssentialMat() function)

Comment: Yeah, I use one camera in 2 different pose and use this findEssentialMat. I directly get the essential matrix when I pass the points and intrinsic matrix. So I guess you meet some problems with 2 cameras instead of 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved due to the difference of the coordinates using.

OpenCV use a right-hand coordinate system. This is to say that the z-axis is projected from xy plane to the viewer direction. And our system is using a left-hand coordinate system. So as long as the changes are related to the z-axis, the result is non-sense.